# Splitting a string based on positions with regex

Tags: regex, string, split

I need to convert this (date) String "12112014" to "12.11.2014"

What i would like to to is:

Split first 2 Strings "12", add ".", 
then split the string from 3-4 to get "11", add "." 
at the end split the last 4 strings (or 5-8) to get "2012"

I already found out how to get the first 2 characters ( "^\d{2}" ), but I failed to get characters based on a position.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever be the programming language, You should try to extract the digits from string and then join them with a ".".

In perl, it can be done as :

```
$_ = '12112014';

s/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/$1.$2.$3/;

print "$_";
```

Answer (score 0):

Without you specifying the language you're after, I've picked javascript:

```
var s = '12012011';
var s2 = s.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/,'$1.$2.$3'));
console.log(s2);  // prints "12.01.2011"
```

The gist of it is that you use `()` to specify groups inside your regular expression and then can use the groups in your replace expression.

Same in Java:

```
String s = "12012011";
String s2 = s.replaceAll("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})", "$1.$2.$3");
System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you could do that only with split.

You could expand your expression to:

```
"(^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4}))"
```

Then access the groups with the Regex language of your choice and build the string you want.

Note that - besides all regex learning - alternatively you could always parse the original string into strongly typed Date or DateTime variables and output the value using the appropriate locales.